# collection_select using different models between value and text methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I am trying to create a `collection_select` field for an object(**user**) that takes its `value_method` from another model (**Product**), and its `text_method` from yet another model (**Product_description**).

**Product** `belongs_to` **Product_description** via **product_description_id**.

**Product_description.rb** has two columns, **:id** and **:name**

How can I set up the `text_method`? The following code provides the correct inputs, but shows the **product_description_id** integer instead of the corresponding text name. How can I get the corresponding "**name**" from the **product_description** table?

```
<%= f.collection_select :product_description_id, @object.products.order(:product_description_id), :product_description_id, :product_description_id %>
```

I tried this, but this gives me an invalid statement.

```
<%= f.collection_select :product_description_id, @object.products.order(:product_description_id), :product_description_id, ProductDescription.find(:product_description_id).name %>
```

Feedback would be much appreciated!

Comment: if you use SimpleForm, it has params for specifying value and label methods.
<% f.input :product_description_id, :as => :select, :label_method => :blah, :value_method => :other_blah %>

Comment: Thanks @iouri. I don't have SimpleForm, but will look into it. My question is in regards to what to put for the `:blah` for the label. I want to include all members of @object.products, and show their corresponding names stored in the product_description table. Do you have any insights on how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't (at least not without adding a method to product that returns the description or wrapping the products in an object with a description method. That is probably a good idea: should users of the product class really have to know the implementation detail  that names are stored in a separate table?

However, remember that collection_select is just a convenience method for a common case. If you don't fit that case there's nothing wrong with using a "normal" select:

```
f.select :product_description_id, @object.products.order(:product_description_id).collect {|product| [product.production_description.name, product.product_description_id]}
```

It would be a good idea to add an `includes` although it will work without.

Comment: Thanks @Frederick. This is returning the correct view, but is submitting the wrong integer. (ie. it's showing the name for product_description_ids 2 and 3,  but when I select one, it's sending either 4 or 5. Give me a sec to see if I can fix it.

Comment: Oh I stuck product.id in there instead of product_desxription_id

Comment: It was an easy fix. Changed the `product.id` at the end to `product.product_description_id`. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score -1):

```
<%= f.collection_select :product_description_id, @object.products.order(:product_description_id).includes(:product_description), :product_description_id, "production_descriptions.name" %>
```

Comment: Thanks @drinehart, but this returns a no method error for product_descriptions.name. Also for product_description.name.